# Limiting the number of CPUs used in SQL Server 2012 Enterprise

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

The platform under consideration is SQL Server 2012 Ent. SP3.

We are in the process of migrating a SQL Server environment to VM but highly feel the server was over spec'd to start.

We want the customer to feel good about going to a VM with less resources as they don't appear to be needed.

To start we want limit the number of CPUs that are currently being allocated.  Is setting the Processor affinity a safe approach? Any *gotchas*?

The server was a dedicated physical SQL Server with 32 cores moving to VMware. The thought was to step down the number of CPUs on the old server prior to going to VM to show the customer.  According to the VM team, having a server with that many CPUs is not necessary due to VM.   Also, the server is basically using less than 10% of the available CPUs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is a little hard to understand.

> We are in the process of migrating a SQL Server environment to VM but
>   highly feel the server was over spec'd to start.
>
> We want the customer to feel good about going to a VM with less
>   resources as they don't appear to be needed.
>
> To start we want limit the number of CPUs that are currently being
>   allocated. Is setting the Processor affinity a safe approach? Any
>   gotchas?

Is the current server a physical and you want to limit the CPU resources it has access to in order to highlight to the customer that it will run fine on a VM with fewer CPU resources?

Assuming yes, processor affinity may work for this, however, it can cause SQL Server to adopt a 1:1 ratio of Schedulers on SQLOS to Cores on the server, which can cause poor utilisation of even the now reduced CPU resources. See [this blog post](https://www.sqlpassion.at/archive/2017/10/02/setting-a-processor-affinity-in-sql-server-the-unwanted-side-effects/) for more information.

A better solution might be to use Resource Governor to limit the amount of CPU for the default pool to control the amount of CPU resources it can use without introducing the 1:1 affinity issue. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/resource-governor/resource-governor?view=sql-server-2017) for more information.

Basically, if you have, say, 24 cores at the moment and want to reduce to 12, then you could set the default pool MAX_CPU_PERCENT to 50. It is not an exact analog for reducing the available cores, but it will give you some confirmation that your workload will be fine with reduced CPU resources.

NOTE: If you enable trace flag 8002 and use processor affinity you can avoid the 1:1 scheduler to core issue. See [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SQL-Server-Support/SQL-Server-Clarifying-The-NUMA-Configuration-Information/ba-p/316753) for more info. Enabling this trace flag requires a restart.

NOTE 2: If your current server is not physical, then just lower the vCPUs for that server to validate (if you're confident the workload can be sustained on fewer cores).

Comment: The resource governor sounds like a safer approach.  Enable RG and I assume in the RG props just need to set the max cpu on the default line item only in the Resource pools section?

Comment: Yes, there is a property called CAP_CPU_PERCENT. Review the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/resource-governor/resource-governor?view=sql-server-2017) though to make sure you have a good understanding of RG.

Comment: I edited the RG props default resource pool via gui and set the Max CPU % to 75, no CAP_CPU_PERCENT via gui, then queried sys.dm_resource_governor_resource_pools MaxCpu% =75, CapCpu%=100.  Should I alter both?

Comment: CAP_CPU_PERCENT is a hard limit, MAX_CPU_PERCENT is only a limit if there are competing resources. In this case, CPU will still go to 100% because CAP_CPU is 100% and you only have 1 pool competing for resources (excluding internal).

Comment: HandyD - Thank you for your assistance on this matter, I have set CAP_CPU_PERCENT.